# OpenVPN on Android 4.4 not working

Tags: networking, 4.4-kitkat, vpn

I'm running CyanogenMod 11 unofficial ROM and I can't seem to get VPN working.

I've tried different OpenVPN clients. All of them connect to the server, but there is no traffic; the connection just gets stuck. The VPN servers work fine on laptop and older android versions.

Has anybody experienced a similar issue and what would be a workaround?

P.S: I've also tried PPTP and L2TP connections. Same issue. Connect but won't work.